Extracting the Day of the Week from DateTime column
I am using data from the Databricks catalog.
My column is of date/time type and is in the format "*14/03/2001 1:30:55 PM (General Date)".
I am trying to extract the day of the week (Monday-Sunday) from the datetime column.
I have tried the following queries:
DayName = SWITCH(TRUE(),
                 MOD(YEAR([YourDateTimeColumn]) * 10000 + MONTH([YourDateTimeColumn]) * 100 + DAY([YourDateTimeColumn]), 7) = 0, "Sunday",
                 MOD(YEAR([YourDateTimeColumn]) * 10000 + MONTH([YourDateTimeColumn]) * 100 + DAY([YourDateTimeColumn]), 7) = 1, "Monday",
                 MOD(YEAR([YourDateTimeColumn]) * 10000 + MONTH([YourDateTimeColumn]) * 100 + DAY([YourDateTimeColumn]), 7) = 2, "Tuesday",
                 MOD(YEAR([YourDateTimeColumn]) * 10000 + MONTH([YourDateTimeColumn]) * 100 + DAY([YourDateTimeColumn]), 7) = 3, "Wednesday",
                 MOD(YEAR([YourDateTimeColumn]) * 10000 + MONTH([YourDateTimeColumn]) * 100 + DAY([YourDateTimeColumn]), 7) = 4, "Thursday",
                 MOD(YEAR([YourDateTimeColumn]) * 10000 + MONTH([YourDateTimeColumn]) * 100 + DAY([YourDateTimeColumn]), 7) = 5, "Friday",
                 MOD(YEAR([YourDateTimeColumn]) * 10000 + MONTH([YourDateTimeColumn]) * 100 + DAY([YourDateTimeColumn]), 7) = 6, "Saturday")

Error: couldn't fold the expression into the data source. Please try a simpler expression.

DayName = SWITCH(TRUE(),
                 FORMAT([YourDateTimeColumn], "dddd") = "Monday", "Monday",
                 FORMAT([YourDateTimeColumn], "dddd") = "Tuesday", "Tuesday",
                 FORMAT([YourDateTimeColumn], "dddd") = "Wednesday", "Wednesday",
                 FORMAT([YourDateTimeColumn], "dddd") = "Thursday", "Thursday",
                 FORMAT([YourDateTimeColumn], "dddd") = "Friday", "Friday",
                 FORMAT([YourDateTimeColumn], "dddd") = "Saturday", "Saturday",
                 FORMAT([YourDateTimeColumn], "dddd") = "Sunday", "Sunday")

Error: Function 'FORMAT' is not allowed as part of calculated column DAX expressions on DirectQuery models.

DayNumber = WEEKDAY([YourDateTimeColumn], 2)
DayName = SWITCH([DayNumber], 
                 1, "Monday", 
                 2, "Tuesday", 
                 3, "Wednesday", 
                 4, "Thursday", 
                 5, "Friday", 
                 6, "Saturday", 
                 7, "Sunday")

Error: function weekday is not allowed as part of calculated column DAX expressions.

DayOfWeek = FORMAT([YourDateTimeColumn], "dddd")

Error: Function 'FORMAT' is not allowed as part of calculated column DAX expressions on DirectQuery models.


DQ mode on Databricks  is more limited than DQ in SQL Server because it uses Apache SQL rather that TSQL in SQL Server.
Quoting from Roche’s Maxim :

Data should be transformed as far upstream as possible, and as far
downstream as necessary.

Try to use date_format function that accepts a format as an argument. This format returns a name of a week day from a timestamp:
SELECT 
  date_format(YourDateTimeColumn, 'EEEE') AS DayName
FROM 
  your_table_name

Otherwise, if your are working with Pyspark :
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_format

df = df.withColumn('DayName', date_format(df['YourDateTimeColumn'], 'EEEE'))

